# If loop in VBA ignoring Else argument

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a gambling simulation in VBA to determine how changes in win/lose probabilities will affect the standard deviation of my results. After running my code several times I have noticed that my Else argument is being skipped and as a result numtries always equals 1. Fail, win and tryagain all represent numbers that sum together to one (fail<1, fail+win<1, fail+win+tryagain=1)

Here is my code.

```
Sub game()
Dim win, tryagain, prize, fail, numtries, winnings, roll As Integer

prize = Sheets("Game 1").Cells(3, 1).Value
win = Sheets("Game 1").Cells(5, 1).Value
tryagain = Sheets("Game 1").Cells(7, 1).Value
fail = Sheets("Game 1").Cells(9, 1).Value

  winnings = 0
  numtries = 1

For i = 1 To 9999

roll = Rnd()

     If roll <= fail Then
     winnings = 0
  Exit For

     ElseIf fail <= roll <= fail + win Then
     winnings = prize * numtries
  Exit For

     Else
     numtries = numtries + 1
  End If

   Next i

Sheets("Game 1").Cells(15, 3).Value = winnings
Sheets("Game 1").Cells(15, 4).Value = numtries

End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: Updated answer to include couple of changes to your code. Copy both Subs into VBA, and run `game2()` with `runs=99` just to see what it is doing. I think you need to maybe think about `numtries`.

Comment: Unrelated but a friendly note that only "roll" is an Integer, the rest are being declared as Variant. You cannot chain Dim like you are doing, it has to be like "dim win as integer, roll as integer", etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find this information out by debugging your application (step through the VBA code using the F8 key). For debugging help, you really should specify the values for all the variables in your code, that you are using, and what you think the correct output *should* be, along with the output *you* are getting. This is so others' can verify your code and determine the correct method.

You define `roll` as integer and then set `roll=Rnd()`, but `Rnd()` is a `float` and returns a number less than 1. This means `roll=1` effectively all the time.

I suspect`fail` is defined as a percentage (or decimal) which is < 1. This mean your condition

`If roll <= fail`is always `FALSE`

and

`fail <= roll <= fail + win` is always `TRUE`.

The rest of the problems, you should be able to work out from here. Does that help?

**Update**
Here is an implementation, and a helper function, that makes things a little bit clearer. In particular, the `for i=1 to 9999` loop has been activated, as it was not running before (set `runs` to change the number of loops).

The first sub is a helper function, `PrintArray`, that is used to print the contents of an array to the worksheet. Copy both procedures into your VBA.

```
Sub PrintArray(Data As Variant, Cl As Range)
    Cl.Resize(UBound(Data, 1), UBound(Data, 2)) = Data
End Sub
```

And `game2()` is a slight update of your code:

```
Sub game2()
Dim win, tryagain, prize, fail, winnings, roll As Double
Dim ans() As Double
Dim numtries, runs As Long

'set variables start
prize = Sheets("Game 1").Cells(3, 1).Value
win = Sheets("Game 1").Cells(5, 1).Value
tryagain = Sheets("Game 1").Cells(7, 1).Value
fail = Sheets("Game 1").Cells(9, 1).Value
runs = 99 'the number of loops
'set variables finish

ReDim ans(runs, 2)

  winnings = 0
  numtries = 1

For i = 1 To runs

    roll = Rnd()

    Select Case roll
        Case 0 To fail
            winnings = 0
        Case fail To (fail + win)
            winnings = prize * numtries
        Case Else
            numtries = numtries + 1 'numtries only gets updated here..
    End Select

    ans(i - 1, 0) = winnings
    ans(i - 1, 1) = numtries
 Next i

PrintArray ans, ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Game 1").[C15]

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Rusan.
I see how this might be a problem but I would like to mention that roll <= fail returns true even when I dim roll as integer.
I tried dim roll as variant and no changes occurred

Comment: @Innovation OK. that rules out a couple of things. But please read my comment about posting all the information and values used for ALL variables, etc...plus output and output you expect. If you cannot be bothered to do this...very few people are going to bothered to guess for themselves. For instance, what is the value of "fail" - you refer to worksheet cells..which you have not shown.....

Comment: FIXED! The debugging tip helped a lot Rusan. I found the faulty line and the culprit -  
fail <= roll <= fail + win isn't a legitimate argument.
fail <= roll And roll <= fail + win worked without a hitch!

Would upvote but no rep :(

Comment: I added a different version. I think it is still not doing what *you* think it is doing as `numtries` is only getting updated some of the time...anyway...take a look to follow what I have done (updated my answer)